# React table - Row selection when the header check box is clicked the rows check boxes are not checked

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-table-v7

I have this table where i have details about the exam schedule of the students. When i select the checkbox of a particular row and click the delete button that row is deleted. Now the problem is that i also have a checkbox in the header the main job of header is to select all the check boxes and delete all the rows. so when i check the header check box all the data related to all the rows is added to the array but the check box of rows is not checked [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/crZt8.png)

The header check box is checked and all the data is stored in selectedFlatRows but the row checkboxes are not checked

This is the code:

```
import {
  useTable,
  useSortBy,
  useGlobalFilter,
  usePagination,
  useRowSelect,
} from "react-table";

import styles from "./BasicTable.module.css";
import { useMemo, useState } from "react";
import { CheckBox } from "./TableCheckBox";
import {
  Box,
  Button,
  Paper,
  Stack,
  Table,
  TableBody,
  TableCell,
  TableContainer,
  TableHead,
  TableRow,
  TextField,
  Typography,
} from "@mui/material";
import SelectComp from "../SelectComp";
import {
  KeyboardDoubleArrowLeft,
  KeyboardDoubleArrowRight,
} from "@mui/icons-material";

function BasicTable({ tableData, tableColumn, addCheck = false, checkBoxFn }) {
  const [deleteOpt] = useState(addCheck);

  const columns = useMemo(() => tableColumn, [tableColumn]);
  const data = useMemo(() => tableData, [tableData]);

  const {
    getTableProps,
    getTableBodyProps,
    headerGroups,
    // rows,
    prepareRow,
    state,
    setGlobalFilter,
    page,
    setPageSize,
    nextPage,
    previousPage,
    canNextPage,
    canPreviousPage,
    gotoPage,
    pageOptions,
    selectedFlatRows,
    pageCount,
  } = useTable(
    {
      columns,
      data,
    },
    useGlobalFilter,
    useSortBy,
    usePagination,
    useRowSelect,
    (hooks) => {
      hooks.visibleColumns.push((columns) => {
        //adding delete column to delete individual row or group of rows
        const checkColumn = {
          id: "selection",
          Header: ({ getToggleAllRowsSelectedProps }) => (
            <CheckBox {...getToggleAllRowsSelectedProps()} />
          ),
          Cell: ({ row }) => (
            <CheckBox
              {...row.getToggleRowSelectedProps()}
              key={row.original.id}
            />
          ),
        };
        if (deleteOpt) {
          return [...columns, checkColumn];
        }
        return [...columns];
      });
    }
  );
  const { globalFilter, pageSize, pageIndex } = state;

  function handleSetPageSize(_, size) {
    setPageSize(Number(size));
  }

  return (
    <Stack spacing={2}>
      <Box className={styles.grid}>
        <Box className={`${styles.filedContainer} ${styles.FC_select}`}>
          <SelectComp
            values={[10, 20, 30]}
            initialValue={pageSize}
            type="selection"
            selectionValue={handleSetPageSize}
            placeholder="table size"
          />
          <Typography>Records</Typography>
        </Box>
        <Box className={`${styles.filedContainer} ${styles.FC_search}`}>
          <Typography>Search :</Typography>
          <TextField
            id="outlined-textarea"
            value={globalFilter || ""}
            type="text"
            onChange={(e) => setGlobalFilter(e.target.value)}
            size="small"
            className={styles.tableSearchFiled}
          />
        </Box>
      </Box>
      <TableContainer component={Paper}>
        <Table aria-label="simple table" {...getTableProps()}>
          <TableHead>
            {headerGroups.map((headerGroup) => (
              <TableRow {...headerGroup.getHeaderGroupProps()}>
                {headerGroup.headers.map((column) => (
                  <TableCell
                    {...column.getHeaderProps(column.getSortByToggleProps())}
                  >
                    {column.render("Header")}
                    <span>
                      {column.isSorted
                        ? column.isSortedDesc
                          ? " "
                          : " "
                        : ""}
                    </span>
                  </TableCell>
                ))}
              </TableRow>
            ))}
          </TableHead>
          {tableData.length !== 0 ? (
            <TableBody {...getTableBodyProps()}>
              {page.map((row) => {
                prepareRow(row);
                return (
                  <TableRow {...row.getRowProps()}>
                    {row.cells.map((cell) => (
                      <TableCell {...cell.getCellProps()}>
                        {cell.render("Cell")}
                      </TableCell>
                    ))}
                  </TableRow>
                );
              })}
            </TableBody>
          ) : (
            <TableBody>
              <TableRow>
                <TableCell>
                  <Typography color="error" m={2}>
                    No record found
                  </Typography>
                </TableCell>
              </TableRow>
            </TableBody>
          )}
        </Table>
        {deleteOpt && tableData.length !== 0 && (
          <Box className={styles.deleteContainer} m={2}>
            <Button
              variant="contained"
              color="error"
              onClick={() => checkBoxFn(selectedFlatRows)}
            >
              Delete
            </Button>
          </Box>
        )}
      </TableContainer>
      <Box className={styles.tableNavigation}>
        <Typography>
          Page{" "}
          <strong>
            {pageIndex + 1} of {pageOptions.length}
          </strong>{" "}
        </Typography>
        <Box component="span" className={styles.tableNavigation}>
          | Go to page :{" "}
          <TextField
            type="number"
            size="small"
            defaultValue={pageIndex + 1}
            onChange={(e) => {
              const pageNumber = e.target.value
                ? Number(e.target.value) - 1
                : 0;
              gotoPage(pageNumber);
            }}
          />
        </Box>
        <Button onClick={() => gotoPage(0)} disabled={!canPreviousPage}>
          <KeyboardDoubleArrowLeft />
        </Button>
        <Button onClick={() => previousPage()} disabled={!canPreviousPage}>
          Previous
        </Button>
        <Button onClick={() => nextPage()} disabled={!canNextPage}>
          Next
        </Button>
        <Button onClick={() => gotoPage(pageCount - 1)} disabled={!canNextPage}>
          <KeyboardDoubleArrowRight />
        </Button>
      </Box>
      <pre>
        <code>
          {JSON.stringify(
            {
              selectedFlatRows: selectedFlatRows.map((row) => row.original),
            },
            null,
            2
          )}
        </code>
      </pre>
    </Stack>
  );
}

export default BasicTable;
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.